# How to Open Applet with JFrames on HTML page load

Tags: java, swing, file-upload, jframe, japplet

Im a newbie in Java. I have a java applet with JFrames on it. it is running on Tomcat. I want to open it on a load. I can run it using a button and the button will post on the servlet and the servlet will call the applet class and call the init() method. Also do I need to export my applet class to .jar instead of using its java(.class) file?

Should I call it like this on HTML?

```
< applet codebase="" code="" archive="" width="800" height="500"> 
</applet>
```

what to put in the codebase? code? archive?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The servlet will not call the Java class. Applets execute at client side, in the browser. Servlet execute at server-side. Readd the applet tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response @JBNizet I created an Upload File functionality in my system by using JFrames. My Problem is it opens on the server and I need it to open in the client side. Maybe because my servlet is the one calling the Upload class. I do some searching and they said that I need to convert my Jframes into Applets. I've done some changes on my class to make in an applet. but I don't know what to do next. Thanks for helping!

Comment: As I said: the servlet is part of a web application. The applet is part of a client applications. These applications are completely different, and the servlet shouldn't even have the applet classes in its classpath. The applet jar file is just a file available for download in the webapp, just like an image or a CSS file. Read the tutorial.

Comment: @JBNizet last question.. so applet is a standalone application? all of its component must be on its jar file right? example its connection to the database, functions and methods? am I right? Thank you very much Sir! This helps me alot.

Comment: An applet is indeed almost like a standalone application running inside the browser. It generally doesn't connect to a database, but communicates using HTTP with the server it comes from, which itself connects to the database.

Comment: Hi Sir! @AndrewThompson Thanks for your advice! Is it more easy to use Java Web Start than creating an applet? Thank you so much Sir!

Comment: Sir @AndrewThompson is Java Web Start Application different in Java Web Application? because my JFrames is called and processed by my Servlets in a Java Application. I have an existing Web Application (it's a serial number tracking system) and I am adding an upload file to database functionality to it.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sir I finally get it working! hahaha Thanks but is it posible for me to launch a JFileChooser from my JFrame? I've launched the file chooser before but not with web start. Thank you so much Sir!

Comment: *"last question.. – Bimbz Aug 23 at 10:29"*  (chuckle) famous last words.  ;)

Comment: Hahaha ok ok I'll just find a work around Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I created an Upload File functionality in my system by using JFrames. My Problem is it opens on the server and I need it to open in the client side.

Easy done. Launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

> Is it more easy to use Java Web Start than creating an applet?

Hell yes. (I was just going to reply 'yes' but felt that did not really cover the emphatic nature of my conviction on the matter.)

> ..is Java Web Start Application different in Java Web Application? because my JFrames is called and processed by my Servlets in a Java Application. I have an existing Web Application (it's a serial number tracking system) and I am adding an upload file to database functionality to it.

The servlet is part of the web-app. The desktop client is the JFrame - launched using Java Web Start from a link in the web app.   The client side desktop app. can consume services of the web app. (e.g. show data obtained from it) or access other public APIs of the web app. (e.g. to search, make an order, save an edited resource..).

> ..is it posible for me to launch a JFileChooser from my JFrame?

Yes.  If the app. is digitally signed, and the launch file requests/is granted `all-permissions`.

Alternately, use the [File Services of the JNLP API](http://www.pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).  But they do not use the standard `JFileChooser`.  More importantly, they return a `FileContents` object(s) rather than `File`.

Comment: Hi Sir Andrew, I've already signed my Jar file but still JNLP fiel chooser won't open. what can I be missing here? Thanks!

Comment: *"JNLP fiel chooser won't open."*  I think you should ask another question on that.  Make sure to validate the JNLP with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/), before adding it to the new question.

Comment: It opens now Sir hahaha Thanks any for JaNeLa. It's only because of my JNLP file.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.  :)

Answer (score 4):

I hope this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/deployingApplet.html) will help to start.

> Also do I need to export my applet class to .jar instead of using its java(.class) file?

Yes, you do.

> the servlet will call the applet class and call the init() method

No, it won't. Your applet jar will be downloaded on your client machine and then java plugin in your web browser will manage it's lifesycle.